# How to reliably detect device type on a MediaRoute select/unselect event

Tags: java, android

I have dug into the Android sources and found that under the hood, each time an Audio route event occurs, an AudioRoutesInfo object is based to the internal updateAudioRoutes method in MediaRouter:

```
      void updateAudioRoutes(AudioRoutesInfo newRoutes) {
                if (newRoutes.mMainType != mCurAudioRoutesInfo.mMainType) {
                    mCurAudioRoutesInfo.mMainType = newRoutes.mMainType;
                    int name;
                    if ((newRoutes.mMainType&AudioRoutesInfo.MAIN_HEADPHONES) != 0
                            || (newRoutes.mMainType&AudioRoutesInfo.MAIN_HEADSET) != 0) {
                        name = com.android.internal.R.string.default_audio_route_name_headphones;
                    } else if ((newRoutes.mMainType&AudioRoutesInfo.MAIN_DOCK_SPEAKERS) != 0) {
                        name = com.android.internal.R.string.default_audio_route_name_dock_speakers;
                    } else if ((newRoutes.mMainType&AudioRoutesInfo.MAIN_HDMI) != 0) {
                        name = com.android.internal.R.string.default_media_route_name_hdmi;
                    } else {
                        name = com.android.internal.R.string.default_audio_route_name;
                    }
                    sStatic.mDefaultAudioVideo.mNameResId = name;
                    dispatchRouteChanged(sStatic.mDefaultAudioVideo);
                }

                final int mainType = mCurAudioRoutesInfo.mMainType;

                boolean a2dpEnabled;
                try {
                    a2dpEnabled = mAudioService.isBluetoothA2dpOn();
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error querying Bluetooth A2DP state", e);
                    a2dpEnabled = false;
                }

                if (!TextUtils.equals(newRoutes.mBluetoothName, mCurAudioRoutesInfo.mBluetoothName)) {
                    mCurAudioRoutesInfo.mBluetoothName = newRoutes.mBluetoothName;
                    if (mCurAudioRoutesInfo.mBluetoothName != null) {
                        if (sStatic.mBluetoothA2dpRoute == null) {
                            final RouteInfo info = new RouteInfo(sStatic.mSystemCategory);
                            info.mName = mCurAudioRoutesInfo.mBluetoothName;
                            info.mDescription = sStatic.mResources.getText(
                                    com.android.internal.R.string.bluetooth_a2dp_audio_route_name);
                            info.mSupportedTypes = ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO;
                            sStatic.mBluetoothA2dpRoute = info;
                            addRouteStatic(sStatic.mBluetoothA2dpRoute);
                        } else {
                            sStatic.mBluetoothA2dpRoute.mName = mCurAudioRoutesInfo.mBluetoothName;
                            dispatchRouteChanged(sStatic.mBluetoothA2dpRoute);
                        }
                    } else if (sStatic.mBluetoothA2dpRoute != null) {
                        removeRouteStatic(sStatic.mBluetoothA2dpRoute);
                        sStatic.mBluetoothA2dpRoute = null;
                    }
                }

                if (mBluetoothA2dpRoute != null) {
                    if (mainType != AudioRoutesInfo.MAIN_SPEAKER &&
                            mSelectedRoute == mBluetoothA2dpRoute && !a2dpEnabled) {
                        selectRouteStatic(ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO, mDefaultAudioVideo, false);
                    } else if ((mSelectedRoute == mDefaultAudioVideo || mSelectedRoute == null) &&
                            a2dpEnabled) {
                        selectRouteStatic(ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO, mBluetoothA2dpRoute, false);
                    }


             }
        }
```

Unfortunately, the only thing I have found that is exposed about the device type in the MediaRouter callbacks, is the internal string resource name of the device (e.g. Phone or Headphones). However, you can see that under the hood, this AudioRoutesInfo object has references to whether the device was a headphone, HDMI etc.

Has anyone found a solution to get at this information? The best way I have found is to use the internal resource names, which is pretty ugly. God, if they would just provide the AudioRoutesInfo object all this information could be accessed without having to rely on a resource hack.